# No such file or directory on all binaries after uninstalling RPM

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-8

This morning I was recompiling an RPM that I need to test that's built with CMake and I went to uninstall the old one which was missing some stuff. After uninstalling the old one, I went to install the new one and suddenly I'm getting "no such file or directory" for every single command I execute. So for example, I try to "ls" and get `/usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory`.

Through some experimenting I found that I could still change directory with `cd`, and when I went to `/usr/bin`,  these binaries are still definitely there because I'm able to list the directory by using tab autocomplete, but even when I'm in that directory and do `./ls`, it gives the same message.

I closed my terminals thinking it was a hosed session, but now my terminal won't launch. I tried using `ssh` to connect, but it refuses my password a few times before saying `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).`.

I have a coworker who had a session open on my machine and he is getting the same errors when trying the same commands. He tried doing an `export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` and the command completed, but it didn't change anything.

What do I do from here?

Comment: (1) `no such file or directory` for executables that are there may mean a [missing loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13409/108618). If every executable is failing then you probably won't be able to do anything from within this OS. In theory, if you mount the filesystem in a working Linux (like from live USB) and put right files in right places, you will fix it; the hard thing is to know all "right files" and "right places", I don't. (2) You tagged `redhat-enterprise-linux` and `centos-8`. How should we interpret this?

Comment: I tagged RedHat and CentOS because that's the architecture. I'm running RedHat 8.4.

Comment: Do absolute paths work for commands? That is, does `/usr/bin/ls` work?  Can you run `/usr/sbin/ldconfig` and does that help?

Comment: @mpez0 I've opted to just cut my losses, recover my work via LiveCD, and just reimage it. This was the worst possible time this could have happened.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Sorry for the problem, but I'm glad you can recover your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was the RPM after all. The binaries and libraries were being installed in the wrong location because I forgot to refactor some of the CMakeLists files, and those directories were not included in the **CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION** list, so when the RPM got removed, it blew away the **/bin**, **/lib64**, and **/include** directories with it.

Whoops...